# Why we can define a function with the same name of a built-in function Racket?

Tags: function, scheme, racket

We can define a new function like this:

```
(define (car x y) (+ x y))
```

And use `car` as an add function. Meanwhile, we lost the built-in function `car`. Why does Racket allow this? How could we recover the lost built-in function, here is `car`.

Comment: The question actually depends on the language level.  If you are in a beginner-level language, trying to shadow the name of a built-in is a syntax error.  e.g. `(define first "1st")` in BSL will raise the syntax error: `first: this name was defined previously and cannot be re-defined`.

Answer (score 3):

Definitions affect the current module only (and, if you export your definition, then any other modules that import your module). You can always import Racket's built-in functions under a different name, if you want to use `car` in your module for something else. For example:

```
(require (only-in racket/base (car racket-car)))
```

Now, you can use `racket-car` to refer to the built-in `car` function.