# How to fix the 'cannot change constant' error

Tags: scheme, racket, variable-assignment, redefinition

I have this code so far

```
(define (max f g) 
  (define (int-max x y)
    (if (> x y) x y))
  (lambda (x) (int-max (f x) (g x))))
```

it gives me the error `define-values: assignment disallowed;
 cannot change constant
  constant: max`

I'm not sure how to fix this or what it means.

Comment: You are trying to change an existing binding: `max` is already defined.
See also [6.6 Assignment and Redefinition](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-set.html) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23144047/124319.

Comment: What language are you using? Because in `#lang racket`, this is absolutely valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `max` is already defined and you are trying to re-define it.

More importantly, name `max` is not appropriate for what you are trying to use it for. You are calling `max` with couple of arguments that are functions. It returns a `lambda` that can be invoked with a variable.

Your envisioning usage such as

```
((max sin cos) 10)
```

A name such as `max-proc-value` would be more appropriate and will avoid the problem that you have run into.

Answer (score 4):

In DrRacket in the bottom left there is a dropdown where you can select lanaguage. From there you can select "Choose language" and click "Show details". For legacy languages such as R5RS you have the option "Disallow redefinition of initial bindings".

Now according to the R5RS your redefinition can only extend the functionality and that for the data types the original binding worked with should work the same in the new definition. The reason for this is the ability to constant fold the code. Thus the code below is invalid:

```
(define + -)
(+ 5 3)
; ==> 7
```

This might look strange but the program is in violation with the report and because of that the result might as well have been the string "banana" as far as the report is concerned. In R5RS you need to make it compatible for it to be Scheme:

```
(define numeric-max max)
(define max
  (lambda (v1 . vs)
    (if (number? v1)
        (apply numeric-max v1 vs)
        (lambda (x) (numeric-max (v1 x) ((car vs) x))))))
```

With R6RS you are free of this by not importing the binding at all:

```
#!r6rs
(import (except (rnrs base) max))

(define (max f g) 
  (define (int-max x y)
    (if (> x y) x y))
  (lambda (x) (int-max (f x) (g x))))
```

If you want to make `max` available you can do the same as in R5RS with named imports:

```
#!r6rs
(import (except (rnrs base) max)
        (only (rnrs control) case-lambda)
        (rename (rnrs base) (max numeric-max)))

(define max
    (case-lambda
      ((v1 v2)
       (if (number? v1)
           (numeric-max v1 v2)
           (lambda (x) (numeric-max (v1 x) (v2 x)))))
      (args
       (apply numeric-max args))))
```

And of coruse this works in `#lang racket` as well:

```
#lang racket
(require (rename-in racket/base [max numeric-max]))      
(define max
    (case-lambda
      ((v1 v2)
       (if (number? v1)
           (numeric-max v1 v2)
           (lambda (x) (numeric-max (v1 x) (v2 x)))))
      (args
       (apply numeric-max args))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put this in the definition window (the upper one) everything works.

```
#lang racket
(define (max f g) 
    (define (int-max x y)
      (if (> x y) x y))
 (lambda (x) (int-max (f x) (g x))))
```

Comment: Which language have you chosen in DrRacket?

Comment: im new to scheme so just the basic one R5RS I think it is

Comment: Ah! R5rs is Scheme, not Racket. Choose “Determine language from source” in the lower left corner of DrRacket and add #lang racket  As your first line

Comment: Thanks it works with that, but how come it doesn't work with scheme

Comment: Well. If I recall correctly the r5rs standard doesn’t specify how a repl works. So the implementor decided it wasn’t allowed. However you can change the behavior in the language menu. Choose the item “choose language”, click “show details” then remove the tick at ‘enforce constant definitions’.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165791/discussion-between-joe-and-soegaard).

Comment: If you want to chat, use the Rackt IRC channel.https://racket-lang.org/irc-chat.html